# How to use an update statement with MySQL while using two inner joins and setting a table to a concatenation?

Tags: mysql, inner-join, concatenation, group-concat

I'm trying to set product.keywords to equal my category.name(s)

I have products that are in multiple categories. I want to concat each category name to product.keyword

Example:

SKU123 product.id is in category.id 1,2, and 3. The category.name is Category 1, Category 2, and Category 3 respectfully.

Sku123's product.keyword is currently "Awesome"

I'd like to write an UPDATE script that will update all my product.keyword

...

SKU123's product.keyword should = Awesome,Category 1, Category 2, and Category 3

...

Yes, comma separated, please :)

I have three tables.

**table named "Product":**

1. Column named "id"

**Table named "category_product":**

1. Column named "product_id"
2. Column named "category_id"

**Table named "category":**

1. Column named "name"
2. Column named "id"

product.id = product id

category_product.product_id = product id

category_product.category_id = category id

category.name = category name

category.id = category id

```
    select p.sku,p.name,p.keywords,c.name,c.id,group_concat(concat(p.keywords,',',c.name)) as new_keywords

    from category_product cp inner join category c on cp.category_id = c.id

inner join product p on p.id=cp.product_id

    where p.keywords >'' and p.sku='CJP-250-TMG10-1874470677';
```

above should give you an idea how everything is connected.

Sorry, this is only my second time using this site. Hopefully you guys have enough information!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `JOIN` is essentially correct. You need to do the `CONCAT(p.keywords)` outside `GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)`, otherwise you'll repeat the original keyword with each category name. And to do it for every product, remove `p.sku` from the `WHERE` clause and use `GROUP BY p.sku`.

```
UPDATE products AS p
JOIN (
    SELECT p.sku, CONCAT(p.keywords, ',', GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)) AS new_keywords
    FROM products AS p
    JOIN category_product AS cp ON p.id = cp.product_id
    JOIN category AS c ON cp.category_id = c.id
    WHERE p.keywords != ''
    GROUP BY p.sku) AS p1 ON p.sku = p1.sku
SET p.keywords = p1.new_keywords
```

The `SELECT` statement that shows what it will store is:

```
SELECT p.sku, p.name, p.keywords, CONCAT(p.keywords, ',', GROUP_CONCAT(c.name)) AS new_keywords
FROM products AS p
JOIN category_product AS cp ON p.id = cp.product_id
JOIN category AS c ON cp.category_id = c.id
WHERE p.keywords != ''
GROUP BY p.sku
```

Comment: Make sure you test it first on a copy of the table

Comment: Why != blank keyword? Wouldn't I want to include the category names for the products with a blank keyword field?

Comment: I got that from your query, which has `WHERE p.keywords > ''`. So I assumed you didn't want to add categories as keywords if there isn't already a keyword there.

Comment: When I try update code --> Error Code: 1064. You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'GROUP BY p.sku' at line 6

Comment: I missed a line when I was converting delete to select. Try it now

Comment: I can't figure out how to use the Update statement. Seems like an issue with GROUP

Comment: OK, I changed it to join with the whole subquery that uses `GROUP BY`.